# How to detect from Activity class when a certain button in a row in RecylerView is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to detect when a certain button (`btn_removeApp`) in a row of a RecyclerView gets triggered. I am expecting that the function, also below, `rvOnClick_btn_AdapterAppsalreadySelected(View view, int position)` gets called when a button in any of the rows in the RecyclerView is clicked, but that does not happen.

Below is my attempt at the code:

**MY Interface to detect the onClick from Activity Class**

```
public interface RV_AppsalreadySelected_BtnClickListener {

public void rvOnClick_btn_AdapterAppsalreadySelected(View view, int position);
}
```

**My Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.class:**

```
public class Adapter_AppsalreadySelected
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.MyViewHolder> {

private List<String> selAppsList;
private MyAppLogger mLog = new MyAppLogger();

private Context context;
private RV_AppsalreadySelected_BtnClickListener btn_clickListener;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tv_selappname;
    public ImageView iv_selappicon;
    public Button btn_removeApp;

    private String mItem;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tv_selappname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_selappname);
        btn_removeApp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_removeApp);

        btn_removeApp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_removeApp);

        btn_removeApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        mItem = item;
        tv_selappname.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(btn_clickListener != null) {
            btn_clickListener.rvOnClick_btn_AdapterAppsalreadySelected(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

}

public Adapter_AppsalreadySelected(Context context,
        List<String> selAppsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.selAppsList = selAppsList;
}

@Override
public Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_appsalreadyselected, parent, false);

    return new Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String app = selAppsList.get(position);
    holder.tv_selappname.setText(app);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return selAppsList.size();
}
}
```

**row_appsalreadyselected.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_selappicon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_selappname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Apps Name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_removeApp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity class: This is where i want to get the onClick Listener:**

```
public class SetupBlocksActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements
    RV_AppsalreadySelected_BtnClickListener {


@Override
public void rvOnClick_btn_AdapterAppsalreadySelected(View view, int position) {
 //THIS FUNCTION NEVER GETS TRIGGERED EVEN WHEN I CLICK ON btn_removeApp on ANY OF THE ROWS IN THE RECYCLERVIEW

}

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting btn_clickListener ?

Comment: am i not doing it right when i do it in the `OnClick(...)` method in `Adapter_AppsalreadySelected.MyViewHolder`?

Comment: Right, but you are asking if it is not already null... where are you making it not null that it would be allowed to enter into the assignment ?

Comment: Where do you initialize `btn_clickListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this line

```
if (context instanceof RV_AppsalreadySelected_BtnClickListener) 
            btn_clickListener = (RV_AppsalreadySelected_BtnClickListener) context;
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: in adapter constructor

Comment: i dont have an `mListener` variable anywhere, did you mean some other variable?

Comment: @user1406716 sry. check new one;)

Comment: trying it, emulator crashed :)

Comment: @user1406716 don't know why it down voted. The problem is that you never initialized your listener. Hope it works

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks ... so I was not assigning the listener. Kind like @jesse.co.tt mentioned but thanks for showing how to do it.

Comment: @user1406716 hoorah!